# Limb in the vocabulary of arbitrary precision integer?

Tags: c++, c, integer, gmp, arbitrary-precision

What does a "limb" refer to in the domain of arbitrary precision integer?

Comment: An easy google: http://www.ontko.com/pub/rayo/gmp/gmp_4.html

Comment: Here's another: *"GMP works by splitting large numbers into small pieces (called limbs), where each piece is stored as a full native computer word."* https://www.nada.kth.se/utbildning/grukth/exjobb/rapportlistor/2012/rapporter12/olofsson_per_12003.pdf

Answer (score -1):

In the GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library (GMP), as mentioned in comments, is the largest integer word available:

```
#ifdef __GMP_SHORT_LIMB
typedef unsigned int        mp_limb_t;
typedef int         mp_limb_signed_t;
#else
#ifdef _LONG_LONG_LIMB
typedef unsigned long long int  mp_limb_t;
typedef long long int       mp_limb_signed_t;
#else
typedef unsigned long int   mp_limb_t;
typedef long int        mp_limb_signed_t;
#endif
#endif
typedef unsigned long int   mp_bitcnt_t;

typedef struct
{
  int _mp_alloc;        /* Number of *limbs* allocated and pointed to by the _mp_d field.  */
  int _mp_size;         /* abs(_mp_size) is the number of limbs the last field points to.  If _mp_size is negative this is a negative number.  */
  mp_limb_t *_mp_d;     /* Pointer to the limbs.  */
} __mpz_struct;

...

typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1];
```

So a limb can be a `unsigned int`, `unsigned long int`, or `unsigned long long int`, depending on the underlying architecture.

GMP then uses multiple limbs to store and calculate multiple precision integers, by applying a very efficient implementation of machine-specific integer code with highly optimized algorithms for multiple-precision arithmetic. The reason to use machine unsigned integers for these calculations is because integer arithmetic is simple, fast, and very realiable, whereas floating-point arithmetic and signed integer arithmetic are not as nearly standarized and portable as unsigned integer arithmetic.